# Using String.Join in order to print a C# array - Performance

Tags: c#, arrays, performance, console.writeline

I want to print an `array` via `Console.writeline`. 
I'm lazy and want to do it in one line, avoiding iterating through all the `array`.

Here is my code:

```
var costumers = new Costumers[10];

// Array initialization...

Console.WriteLine("Initial array: '{0}'",string.Join(Environment.NewLine,costumers.ToList()) );

Array.Sort(costumers);
```

Is it OK to use `String.Join` for this purpose or it decreases performance dramatically?
Is there an elegant way to do it?

Thanks,
Paul

Comment: Compared to the I/O costs, the string operations are negligible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is absolutely nothing wrong with using `String.Join`: the method is so straightforward that there is hardly anything that could go wrong implementing it. All you need is a `StringBuilder`, a single loop, and a `bool` flag to skip pre-pending the separator the first time around.

You could slightly improve your code by removing `ToList()` from the call, because `Join` accepts `IEnumerable<T>`:

```
Console.WriteLine("Initial array: '{0}'", string.Join<Costumer>(Environment.NewLine, costumers) );
```

Comment: Unfortunately it does not compiles, when I pass the costumers array without the .ToList(), the compiler says its ambiguous invocation

as String.Join can get(string, object[])
And String.Join<Costumer>(string, IEnumerable<Costumer>

How can I solve this? Is there any param/flag I can give the compiler?

Thanks

Comment: add the part with the `<Costumer>` or a direct cast